# 1/velocity for higher dimensions

Tags: kinematics, vectors, velocity, differentiation, speed

I have a somewhat basic question. I am sorry if it trivial.

Denote the velocity by $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ suppose that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to parametrize $t$ in $x$ and compute $\frac{dt}{dx}$. In the 1D case $\frac{dt}{dx}$ is just the inverse of $v$. Is it correct that in the general case it is equal to $v/||v||^2$ because the 1D case should be satisfied elementwise?

Comment: 1. It's not really clear what you mean by "the general case" - in general, velocity is measured along a *path*, not all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is no function $t(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, only along the path, so it's ill-defined to speak of $\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}$. 2. Are you perhaps looking for the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)=

Comment: $\dfrac{\overrightarrow{v}}{v^{2}}$ is a vector so it can’t be $\frac 1v$ just for scalar is true

Comment: I should be formulating this as a mathematics problem and not as a physics one. I understand less of physics than I do of mathematics :3